# What changes do I need to make to my algorithm to make this scene from a different angle?

Tags: algorithms, loops

The code below is in F#. It creates a scene which looks like a perspective coming from the top left. I thought if I would change `i % j = w` then it would come from the top right instead, but that doesn't work. So what change do I need to make for it to be able to come from the top right, bottom left, bottom right and even the top centre?

```
open System

let w = Console.WindowWidth
let h = Console.WindowHeight

for i in 1 .. w - 1 do
    for j in 1 .. h - 1 do
        Console.SetCursorPosition(i, j)
        if i % j = 0 then printf "."

Console.Read() |> ignore
```

Here is what the program looks like.

```
 .......................................................................................................................  . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .
   .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .  .
    .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .   .
     .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .    .
      .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .     .
       .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .      .        .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .       .
         .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .        .
          .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .         .
           .          .          .          .          .          .          .          .          .          .
            .           .           .           .           .           .           .           .           .
             .            .            .            .            .            .            .            .            .
              .             .             .             .             .             .             .             .
               .              .              .              .              .              .              .
                .               .               .               .               .               .               .
                 .                .                .                .                .                .                .                  .                 .                 .                 .                 .                 .
                   .                  .                  .                  .                  .                  .
                    .                   .                   .                   .                   .
                     .                    .                    .                    .                    .
                      .                     .                     .                     .                     .
                       .                      .                      .                      .                      .
                        .                       .                       .                       .
                         .                        .                        .                        .
                          .                         .                         .                         .
                           .                          .                          .                          .
                            .                           .                           .                           .
                             .                            .                            .                            .
```

Comment: You've written "algorithm" but, really, this seems to be a programming problem, which is off-topic, here. Also, I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Indeed, I had flagged this question as off-topic too although I answered it  anyway. I just took a little bit more thought. I believe that the OP, as probably a newcomer to programming and computer science, may believe this question is about the correct algorithm that can produce the desired output. In a way, he is right.  But then almost every programming problem can be treated as a question about algorithm.

Comment: @Apass.Jack I agree that there's often no clear dividing line between designing an algorithm and writing a program. For me, this is on the programming side, though, as it's essentially "Here's a program that does X; how do I modify it to do Y?" But this is certainly something that reasonable people can disagree on. However, I would say that you shouldn't flag a question as off-topic and answer it: those are kind of contradictory acts.

Comment: @DavidRicherby, indeed, I had said (implicitly) that I had made contradictory acts, too.

Comment: I would have thought it could be considered an algorithm, that's why I thought it was best suited here. Otherwise I would have posted it on Stack Overflow and probably gotten a much quicker answer, but I wanted it in the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try replacing the original condition `i % j == 0` with the following conditions? They work for me.

- For a perspective coming from the top right, `(w-i) %j == 0`
- For a perspective coming from the bottom left, `i %(h-j) == 0`
- For a perspective coming from the bottom right, `(w-i) % (h-j) == 0`
- For a perspective coming from the the top centre, `(w/2-i) % j == 0`

Comment: Thank you! Funnily enough I tried some of those before but never used parentheses.